# How can I convert an Integer field to a Real field in a shapefile?

Tags: shapefile

How can I convert an Integer field to a Real field in a shapefile ?

I'm searching a tool, or a way to do that (may be under QGis ?!).

Regards

Comment: Point of clarification: shapefiles store their attributes in .dbf files, whose only numerical data type is an ASCII-encoded fixed-width, fixed-precision decimal: they do not directly store true floating point values.  (*Some* software will correctly interpret ASCII decimal points when they appear even in a zero-precision ("integer") field, but it would be unwise to rely on this without extensive testing.)

Answer (score 3):

The field type is static once created.  You will need to make a new field in the field calculator with type 'Decimal number (real)' and use the field calculator to copy any existing data from the integer field.